# SQL Case Condition On Inner Join

Tags: sql

I am currently trying to join a table to itself to check if for one email there exist two or more Ids. 
I am trying to join my table with itself on its email. I then wanted to query my table with a case condition saying if the count of the email in the nested query > 1 then select the latest modified record in the outer table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM table1  <-- outer table
WHERE email IN 
      (SELECT email, COUNT(*) 
      FROM table1 as src
      INNER JOIN table1 ON src.Email = table1.Email AND src.Id = table1.id
      GROUP BY src.Email)
```

How can I write a query to say if the count for the given email is greater than 1 then select the latest record from the outer table?

Comment: What database management system are you using? SQL server? what version?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you go through all that trouble?  How about just selecting the last modified record:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
where t1.modified_dt = (select max(tt1.modified_dt)
                        from table1 tt1
                        where tt1.email = t1.email
                       );
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do it using window functions:

```
DECLARE @Tab TABLE (ID INT, Email VARCHAR(100), LastModified DATE)

INSERT @Tab
VALUES (1,'testemail@none.com','2019-12-01'),
       (2,'testemail@none.com','2019-11-19'),
       (3,'otheremail@none.com','2019-12-15')


SELECT *
FROM(
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY t.Email ORDER BY t.LastModified DESC) rn, t.*
    FROM @Tab t
    ) t2
WHERE t2.rn = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

If by latest you mean the latest id number (the maximum number) then this should help you

```
With cte AS 
(
  SELECT email,
         COUNT(id) OVER (PARTITION BY email) AS CountOfIDs,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARITION BY email ORDER BY ID DESC) AS IdIndex
  FROM table1
)
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE CountOfIDs > 1 AND IdIndex = 1
```